# Deleting cell data when it is a specific date

Tags: excel, excel-formula

If A1 contained the number 5 and A2 contain the date 7/1/23 when we reached the date of 7/1/23 I want to delete the number 5 in cell A1. Can anyone assist with a simple formula for this? Thank you!

Comment: You need VBA for this.

Comment: Is it a question of visibility? Then you could apply conditional formatting based on the current date. Is it a question of using the value within another formula - e.g. summing values - then you could use e.g. `SUMIFS` ... maybe you should give us more information **why** you have this requirement

Comment: This is being used for a points attendance calendar. For each infraction, an employee has they can accrue pts. 1.00, .50, or .25 after 6 months the pts fall off. I already have the EDATE formula calculating the 6 months now I need assistance removing the pts when it hit that specific date. I hope this makes sense

Comment: I guess you need to share the formula in `A1`?

Comment: If cell A1 contained the date of 1/1/2022 and cell A2 contained the number 1.00 and cell A3 contained the date of 7/1/22 (6 months from 1/1/2022) I want to now remove 1.00 from cell A2 because I have met the criteria of 7/1/22.

Comment: I guess you need to share the formula in `A2`.

Comment: It would be easier to help you, if you provide some sample data. Will you calculate with the points in later steps - or is it, as already asked - just a question of visiblity?

Comment: there is no formula in cell A2 it is a manual entry of 1.00

Comment: I do not know how to add a sample to this sorry

Comment: Based o your description, you cannot do this in Excel using a formula, it would have to be a procedural language like a VBA script.  *Fundamental* to excel is the idea that cells do not “push” data into other cells.  Rather, a cell *pulls* its result from other cells based on the formula.  A cell must either contain a value (like your 1.00) *OR* contain a formula of how to derive a value, but never both.  You would need the source data to be in a different column and then formula in A2 would look at the two dates, and either say “I’m blank” or “I am equal to the value in F2.”

Answer (score 0):

---

Hey there!

What you want to do within the same cell as the value 5 may require some more skilled coding that allows the cell to hold data and a formula that updates itself. However I can recommend another way that achieves what you want but also retains some history.

The left set is what your result would look like if the date is older than todays date. The right being if todays date has not reached the date you specified.

Before row contains the points that would currently exist, while after would contain the points after the date affects the "drop off" you would like.

Then an If statement just compares whether todays date is older/same/or newer than the target date. (To make this formula more dynamic, you can replace B5 with "today()")

```
=IF(B5>=B3,"",B1)
```

or

```
=IF(TODAY()>=B3,"",B1)
```

Hope this helps!

---

What it should look like:

[image: Image Example]